# .gitignore not work in any case, what's the failing point here?

Tags: git, gitignore

.gitignore not work in any what were tried such as cases:

- The content is in any case
  README.md
  Readme.md
  readme.md
- It's already cleared,
  `git rm --cached README.md`
- the Readme.md file in local dir is removed

but still when doing git push, it'll clear, erase the file lives in remote repo

where's and what's the failure?
help me!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you trying to remove `README.md`, `Readme.md`, `readme.md` which was previously tracked? why did you do `git rm --cached .gitignore`? What failed? Please try reconstructing the sentence and the question as a whole

Answer (score 2):

If the file is already tracked in the remote repository, you need to remove it.

Try, for testing:

- clone the remote repo in a new local folder
- add its exact name to a .gitignore: `echo README.md>>.gitignore`
- delete it locally: `git rm README.md` (or `git rm --cached README.md` if you want to keep it around)
- add, commit and push: `git add .; git commit -m "delete README"; git push`

Make sure to use the right case for the file to remove, and do not delete the `.gitignore`.